# Does being equal to a riemann integrable function almost everywhere imply riemann integrability for a bounded function?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

> Let f,g : [a,b] $
> \mathrm{\rightarrow}
> $
> $
> \mathrm{R}
> $
> bounded and f $
> \mathrm{\in}{\mathcal{R}}{\mathrm{[}}{a}{\mathrm{,}}{b}{\mathrm{]}}
> $
> and $
> \mathrm{D}
> $
> $
> \mathrm{{=}}{\mathrm{\{}}{\mathrm{x}}\mathrm{\in}{\mathrm{[}}{\mathrm{a}}{\mathrm{,}}{\mathrm{b}}{\mathrm{]}}\mathrm{\mid}{\mathrm{f}}{\mathrm{(}}{\mathrm{x}}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\ne}{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{(}}{\mathrm{x}}{\mathrm{)}}{\mathrm{\}}}
> $ is of measure zero.
> Does it imply g $
> \mathrm{\in}{\mathcal{R}}{\mathrm{[}}{a}{\mathrm{,}}{b}{\mathrm{]}}
> $?

My answer to it was;

Consider $h:[a,b] \mathrm{\rightarrow}{R}$ where $h(x)= f(x)-g(x)$ then the set of discontinuities of $h$ is $\mathrm{D}$, which is of measure zero; therefore by Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability h$
\mathrm{\in}{\mathcal{R}}{\mathrm{[}}{a}{\mathrm{,}}{b}{\mathrm{]}}
$.So, as h,f $
\mathrm{\in}{\mathcal{R}}{\mathrm{[}}{a}{\mathrm{,}}{b}{\mathrm{]}}
$ so f-h = g $
\mathrm{\in}{\mathcal{R}}{\mathrm{[}}{a}{\mathrm{,}}{b}{\mathrm{]}}
$.

Where did I go wrong in my argument, I don't understand. I do know that the answer to this question is that g$
\mathrm{\notin}{\mathcal{R}}{\mathrm{[}}{a}{\mathrm{,}}{b}{\mathrm{]}}
$, I do have examples supporting the non integrability of g; but I just don't see where I went wrong. Any explanation or suggestion or solution is appreciated.

Comment: The set of discontinuities is not equal to $D$ as you see with $1_{\mathbb Q}$. Even though $f(x) \neq g(x)$ has measure zero, that doesn't stop its limit points from lying in $D^c$, so points in $D^c$ can also be points of discontinuity as $1_{\mathbb Q}$ demonstrates to the extreme.